# How I can get the item from Arraylist<String>?

Tags: java, android

I'm saving some list in `Arraylist` String via `SharedPreferences`. I can save but when I want to show items via `custom adapter`, I can not get it.

I tired:

```
user.get(i).indexOf(5); This gives error and all indexOf.
```

My list coming like this:

```
[InstagramUserSummary(super=dev.niekirk.com.instagram4android.requests.payload.InstagramUserSummary@a4acf205, is_verified=false, profile_pic_id=1773528799482591987_1654599017, is_favorite=false, is_private=false, username=ququletta, pk=1654599017, profile_pic_url=https://instagram.fada1-5.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8d99014623ed527e52512a20002d884b/5C387E45/t51.2885-19/s150x150/31203725_200759604054857_5778864946146181120_n.jpg, has_anonymous_profile_picture=false, full_name=Ququletta)]
```

I want to take from this list username and profile_pic_url.

I tired also make this `ArrayList<String>` to custom model but I could not.

Any solution?

Comment: share your code so I can understand what's going on

Comment: try `user.get(i).getProfilePicUrl()` if you have made getter for the property

Comment: I could not make the getter. Can you share a example @Abdul Kawee?

Comment: @Nina share your model class

Comment: I shared my adapter @Rahul Chokshi

Comment: I do not know what I will do @Andy Turner :)

Comment: share your class code where you pass data to the adapter class

Comment: Classic Recylecer view setAdapter bro. @Rahul Chokshi.

Comment: that's not I meant, share Java class code where did you get data from the network and assign to the adapter.

Comment: This is not important if you know the solution. Because I give you the data. I set the data like my example. @Rahul Chokshi

Comment: because I want to know how many elements in the side ArrayList, that's why you got error may be

Comment: All elements in the example. Not less and more. @Rahul Chokshi

Comment: check size of `ArrayList` before you sent to the adapter, so you can understand `ArrayList` is not null

Comment: ArrayList is not null. I make System.out.println in adapter and ArrayList is coming.

Comment: share all error logcat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Arraylist<String> listNames=new Arraylist<>();
listNames.add("username1");
listNames.add("username2");
listNames.add("username3");
.
.
```

// to get each item from arraylist you can do following:

```
for(int i=0;i<listNames.size();i++)
{
String username = listNames.get(i);
}
```

Comment: If I can get the item, I'll set it in setText. This is the problem, I can not get the item -_-

Comment: send your code...i think you mistak somewhere @Nina